# Show that there exists an unique holomorphic extension $\tilde{f} : U \to \mathbb{C}$ of $f$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be an open subset and $f :U \setminus \mathbb{C}^{n-2} \to \mathbb{C}$ a holomorphic function. Show that there exists an unique holomorphic extension $\tilde{f} : U \to \mathbb{C}$ of $f$.

I'm pretty sure this is an application of the Riemann extension theorem which says that for a holomorphic map $f$ on an open subset $U$ if $g:U \setminus Z(f) \to \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic and locally bounded near $Z(f)$, then $g$ can be extended to $\tilde{g}:U \to \mathbb{C}$.

Now the tricky part is to figure out for which holomorphic map $\mathbb{C}^{n-2}$ is the zero set. Is there a way I could gain some intuition for this if I consider a lower dimensional example?

Comment: Do you know Hartogs' extension theorem ? It may help you